Stop repeated confirmation of change to recurring event in Sequoia?
I have several repeating events, the instances of which I constantly change.
For years and decades, macOS only prompted me once, upon the first change to any instance, to confirm whether I wanted that change to be made to all following instances. It is rare that I ever would want the change to one instance to become a change to all following instances. Mac did not re-ask for this same confirmation when I made a second or third or subsequent change to any one said instance of the recurring event series.
Since updating my primary Mac to version 15 Sequoia, I am now asked on that computer every time I make a change to an instance of an event series. The edited event instance still says “Repeats weekly” in the “Get Info” .
On my secondary Mac, which still runs Sonoma, and is synced to the same calendar over iCloud, the edited event instance does not ask whether I want to propagate the change, and it does not say it is still a repeating event after any once change is made.
Is there any way to stop that re-ask, to restore the previous behavior of Sonoma in the new Sequoia?



When you change a recurring event and decline to change the following occurrences of that event, is the changed event still recurrent, or does it become a one-off?

I don’t understand your question, @LincD.

When you click an event to open the info sheet, a recurring event will show the repeat frequency below the date; e.g., “Repeats weekly.” A non-recurring event won’t have a frequency.

On Sequoia, the edited event instance still says “Repeats weekly”. On another Mac still running Sonoma, synced to the same calendar over iCloud, the edited event instance does not say it is still repeating. I’ve added a little more detail now in the original question.

OK, I confirmed this. It's a bug.
